# How to insert number into string

Tags: python, python-requests, generator

I mean we have some string like

```
'Some text here (text..="{}",text..="{}") \
generator/number/text..={}/text..={}`'
```

I would like to insert a range of numbers to this string that gets output like:

```
'Some text here (text..="{0}",text..="{1}") \
generator/number/text..={0}/text..={1}`'
```

By the way, it can be also like:

```
'Some text here (text..="{0}",text..="{1}", text..="{2}") \
generator/number/text..={0}/text..={1}`/text..={2}'
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: There is no code yet because I don't know how to do it

Comment: What's your desired input and output?

Comment: input:
'Some text here (text..="{}",text..="{}", text..="{}") \
generator/nubmer/text..={}/text..={}/text..={}'
output:
'Some text here (text..="{0}",text..="{1}", text..="{2}") \
generator/nubmer/text..={0}/text..={1}/text..={2}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
a_str = 'Some text here (text..="{}",text..="{}"\ngenerator/nubmer/text..={}/text..={}'

formatter = lambda line: line.format(*map(lambda num: f"{{{num}}}", range(line.count("{}"))))

formatted = '\n'.join(map(formatter, a_str.split('\n')))

print(formatted)
```

**output:**

```
Some text here (text..="{0}",text..="{1}"
generator/nubmer/text..={0}/text..={1}
```

Comment: but your output give me string like:
'Some text here (text..="{0}",text..="{1}", text..="{2}") \
generator/nubmer/text..={3}/text..={4}/text..={5}'

But I need something like:
'Some text here (text..="{0}",text..="{1}", text..="{2}") \
generator/nubmer/text..={0}/text..={1}`/text..={2}'

Comment: My assumption was the string was all on a single line. I've updated my answer. please take a look

Comment: one more question regarding output:
your code output :
Some text here (text..="0",text..="1"
generator/nubmer/text..=0/text..=1
But I need with '{}' like :
Some text here (text..="{0}",text..="{1}"
generator/nubmer/text..={0}/text..={1}

Sorry for the additional question

Answer (score 0):

You could create it on the fly based on your inputs.

```py
text_list = ["text A", "text B"]

output = 'Some text here (' + \
    ','.join('text..="{}"'.format(single_text) for single_text in text_list) + \
 ')'
```

If you don't need to do it as a `"...".format()` string, but can enter your values directly.

Which will result in

```py
>>> output
'Some text here (text..="text A",text..="text B")'
```

If you need the second row as well, feel free to adapt this to your liking by repeating and adapting the `','.join(...)` part as needed.

Answer (score 0):

use an `f` string:

```
number = 23 # fore example

example_string = f"String {number}"
```

would output:

```
String 23
```

using an `f` string (see the `f` before the string) means whatever you put inside the curly brackets is a variable, the cleanest way of putting numbers into strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
base_1 = 'Some text here'
base_2 = 'generator/nubmer/'

for j in range(10):
  base_1 += "text..={"+ f"{j}" + "},"
  base_2 += "text..={"+ f"{j}" +"}/"

base_1 = base_1[:-1]
base_2 = base_2[:-1]
print(base_1, '\n', base_2)




Some text heretext..={0},text..={1},text..={2},text..={3},text..={4},text..={5},text..={6},text..={7},text..={8},text..={9} 
 generator/nubmer/text..={0}/text..={1}/text..={2}/text..={3}/text..={4}/text..={5}/text..={6}/text..={7}/text..={8}/text..={9}
```

Answer (score -1):

My personal preference is to use %:

```
a = 1
b = 3.21209

x = 'This is a string with an integer: %i, a 2-decimal float: %.2f and a 5-decimal float: %.5f' % (a, b, b)
print(x)
```

This is a string with an integer: 1, a 2-decimal float: 3.21 and a 5-decimal float: 3.21209